# The serialize uid number increases the size of the array of bytes to send?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to send an `array` of `bytes` with 6 fields `(char, boolean[], char, byte[], int, and byte)`. Each field has a defined size, therefore my `array` of `bytes` must have a size limit as big as the sum of the 5 fields.

My question is this: The number serialize uid increases the final size of my `bytes` `array` to send? (if the answer is yes I must find another way to convert `array` of `bytes`)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? None of the data types have SerialVersionUID.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, **yes** the default Java Serialization mechanism does include the serial version id in the bytes that it outputs (and expects when it reads it back in). The full details are here http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915, it also includes other stuff too.

You can override this behaviour by implementing Externalizable, as per http://geekexplains.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/externalizable-in-java-what-is-it-used.html.

You may also prefer to use a library like protobuf or msgpack.